# Print array inside html document formatted as array and not a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [1, "one", 2, "two"];
```

How do you print an array inside html document element formatted as:

> ```
> [1, "one", 2, "two"]
> ```

Comment: Have you tried maybe using `someElement.innerHTML = [1, "one", 2, "two"]`?

Comment: did you try `JSON.stringify(array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `JSON.stringify()`, for example yields this:

```js
var arr = [1, "one", 2, "two"];

document.querySelector("#id").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr)
```

```html
<p id="id"></p>
```

If you want the spaces behind the commas you need to build up the string for the element, like so:

```js
var arr = [1, "one", 2, "two"];

let output = "[";

arr.forEach(e => output += JSON.stringify(e) + ", ");

output  = output.substring(0, output.length-2)

output += "]"

document.querySelector("#id").innerHTML = output
```

```html
<p id="id"></p>
```

Comment: The second example (the one that replaces the comma) may produce wrong results giving that there are strings in the array and that those strings may have commas in them.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```

Example:

```js
let arr = [1, 'a', '2', 'b'];

document.getElementById('p1').textContent = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the tools Stackoverflow offers you to format your post?

Comment: It was my first post here, i wasnt sure how to use them.
updated my answer :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can use runnable code snippetts for examples. Here is a [**list**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) of all the things you can do to make your answer look better. Happy reading!

Comment: Thank you! 
I learned how to format my answer in a question about formatting code, amusing.